# nginx reverse proxy worked on LAN but not public

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, http-redirect

I am setting up a `Nginx` reverse proxy using these `docker` images

- `nginx`
- `jwilder/docker-gen`
- `jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion`

The host where these containers are located is given public IP address so that the web app can be accessed from the internet. We registered the subdomain and set the public IP address to that subdomain.

When I test the configuration, the web app worked and https also worked but from LAN only (we have local DNS server that has the subdomain paired to a local server IP address.

But when I tried accessing it from internet it gives 301 redirected too many times. And yes I saw in the `Nginx` log the server logged around 20s 301 redirections and then stopped.

I am still clueless about what is wrong with the configuration. I used this template https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/master/nginx.tmpl for the auto-generated configuration files with a little modification in the location part (`proxy_connect_timeout`, `proxy_send_timeout`, `proxy_read_timeout`, `proxy_send_lowat`) to make our web app not 502 gateway timeout from long processing.

Can anyone point where my configuration failed?

```
# fhij.abcd.co.id
upstream fhij.abcd.co.id {
                                ## Can be connected with "nginx-proxy" network
                        # fhid_web_1
                        server 172.20.0.8:8069;
}
server {
        server_name fhij.abcd.co.id;
        listen 80 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
        server_name fhij.abcd.co.id;
        listen 443 ssl http2 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/fhij.abcd.co.id.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/fhij.abcd.co.id.key;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/certs/fhij.abcd.co.id.dhparam.pem;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/fhij.abcd.co.id.chain.pem;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
        include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://fhij.abcd.co.id;
                proxy_connect_timeout      9990;
                proxy_send_timeout         9990;
                proxy_read_timeout         9990;
                proxy_send_lowat           12000;
        }
}
```

These are the access.log I got from accessing from internet

```
fhij.abcd.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:42 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.abcd.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.abcd.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.abcd.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.abcd.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.abcd.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.abcd.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.abcd.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.abcd.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.abcd.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:45 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.abcd.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:45 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.abcd.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:46 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.abcd.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:46 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.abcd.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:46 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.abcd.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:46 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.abcd.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:46 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.abcd.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:47 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.abcd.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:47 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.abcd.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:47 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
fhij.abcd.co.id 162.158.178.186 - - [22/Nov/2019:03:57:47 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; YAL-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.96 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

And these are from LAN

```
fhij.abcd.co.id 192.168.130.127 - - [22/Nov/2019:05:21:29 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 303 215 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0"
fhij.abcd.co.id 192.168.130.127 - - [22/Nov/2019:05:21:29 +0000] "GET /web HTTP/2.0" 303 227 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0"
fhij.abcd.co.id 192.168.130.127 - - [22/Nov/2019:05:21:29 +0000] "GET /web/login HTTP/2.0" 200 4383 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0"
fhij.abcd.co.id 192.168.130.127 - - [22/Nov/2019:05:21:29 +0000] "GET /web/content/269-ceb8fb1/web.assets_common.0.css HTTP/2.0" 499 0 "https://fhij.abcd.co.id/web/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0"
fhij.abcd.co.id 192.168.130.127 - - [22/Nov/2019:05:21:29 +0000] "GET /web/content/276-771d39e/web.assets_frontend.0.css HTTP/2.0" 499 0 "https://fhij.abcd.co.id/web/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0"
fhij.abcd.co.id 192.168.130.127 - - [22/Nov/2019:05:21:29 +0000] "GET /web/webclient/qweb?mods= HTTP/2.0" 304 0 "https://fhij.abcd.co.id/web/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0"
fhij.abcd.co.id 192.168.130.127 - - [22/Nov/2019:05:21:29 +0000] "POST /web/webclient/bootstrap_translations HTTP/2.0" 200 87 "https://fhij.abcd.co.id/web/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0"
```

Why it is so different? `Nginx` response to internet request was 301 and response to LAN was 303

Comment: Is your upstream variable name really the same as the server name?

Comment: I'm sorry do you mean this `upstream fhij.abcd.co.id`?

Comment: And by server name do you mean this `server_name fhij.abcd.co.id` if it is then yes I think I have it identical

Comment: Is it the app doing the redirecting or is it `nginx`?

Comment: I believe the app `Odoo` only listen and not doing redirection. I'm using `Odoo` v12 with built in werkzeug web server

Comment: I would try changing the upstream name to something generic plus updating the proxy_pass and seeing if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out there is a mistake in our Cloudflare DNS and WAF configuration. Modifying these configuration fixed this issue.